# OUT parameter of MySQL stored procedure is null after calling stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I've created a stored procedure to return a value for row count of any table I pass in as an "IN" parameter, and output that rowcount to an OUT parameter

```
PROCEDURE `GetCount`(in tblname varchar(255), out rowcount int)
BEGIN
    SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ',tblname);
    SET @sql_text2 = concat(@sql_text1,' INTO ');
    SET @sql_final = concat(@sql_text2,  rowcount);

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END
```

when I open a query window in MySQL workbench and do the following:

```
set @tablename = 'my_table_name;
set @cnt = -9998;
call GetCount(@tablename,@cnt);
SELECT @cnt;
```

the value of @cnt is NULL.

Is my method of testing the stored proc incorrect, or is the stored proc to blame?

Comment: You are preparing from sql_text1... so when do sql_text2 and sql_final get executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test methodology is valid, but you have made three errors in the procedure.

Error #1 you are using the wrong variable for the prepared statement.

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
```

This should have been...

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_final;
```

Error #2 This doesn't do what you intend:

```
SET @sql_final = concat(@sql_text2,  rowcount);
```

This concatenates the value of `@sql_text2` with *the value of* `rowcount`.  Since `rowcount` is an `out` parameter, it is null at this point.  If any argument to `CONCAT()` is null, then the result is also null, so you are actually setting `@sql_final` to null.  If not for error #1, either the `PREPARE` or subsequent `EXECUTE` would have thrown an error about `...the right syntax to use near NULL at line 1`.

Here's what you actually intended, the literal string 'rowcount':

```
SET @sql_final = concat(@sql_text2,  'rowcount');
```

...but that would also fail, because `rowcount` is a program variable.  Prepared statements run with session scope, not program scope, so program variables are out of scope in a prepared statement.

The fix requires you to use a user-defined variable, which has session scope, and then copy it into the program variable, as @nbk illustrated in their answer.

```
SET @sql_final = concat(@sql_text2,  '@rowcount');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
SET rowcount = @rowcount;
```

Note that program variables like `rowcount` and user-defined variables like `@rowcount` are from completely different namespaces, so there's no need for the names to be the same and no need for the names to be different.

Error #3 is not strictly an error, in the sense that it isn't stopping your code from working, but here's a note about a potentially dangerous practice.

You are accepting a table name as input, which opens up a security vulnerability called SQL Injection, where malicious input can cause unexpected/unauthorized results.  Even if the argument can be made that this input comes from a trusted source, that argument is disregarded as a matter of best practice, because future changes could invalidate that assumption.  It is worth your time to learn to do this, and do it consistently so that it becomes second-nature to you.

You can safely escape a table name, column name, or other object identifier in MySQL by replacing any embedded backtick with a double backtick, then prepending and appending a single backtick on each end.

You can do this at the top of the procedure...

```
SET tblname = CONCAT('`',REPLACE(tblname,'`','``'),'`');
```

...or inline...

```
SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ',CONCAT('`',REPLACE(tblname,'`','``'),'`'));
```

...but of course not both.  In the second example, the nested `CONCAT()` isn't strictly necessary, so this would also work, but the intention is less obvious:

```
SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ','`',REPLACE(tblname,'`','``'),'`');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this stored procdure:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetCount //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetCount`(IN tblname varchar(255), OUT rowcount int)
BEGIN

  SET @sql_text1 = concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ',tblname);
  SET @sql_text1 = concat(@sql_text1,' INTO ');
  SET @sql_text1 = concat(@sql_text1, ' @rowcount;' );

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  Set rowcount = @rowcount;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The idea is that mysql stores the count into the sessionvariable @rowcount which will be created automatically. The rest is simple getting the result  to the proper variable.