# MySQL procedure call from trigger always returns null for out parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, procedure, out-parameters

My stored procedure OUT parameter, always return a null value.

Here is sample Table, Trigger and Procedure code.

Table: `test`

Columns:

- `id - Int`
- `status - enum(‘pass’, ‘fail’)`  (null is allowed)

Values in a table:

```
id  |  status
1   |  null
```

Trigger:

```
create trigger BEFORE_UPDATE_TEST before update on `test` for each row begin

    call Test_BEFORE_UPDATE_TEST(old.id, @updatedStatus);

       ## I always get @updatedStatus null/nil

    if (@updatedStatus is not null and @updatedStatus <> new.status) then
        set new.status = @updatedStatus;
    end if;

end;
```

Procedure:

```
create procedure Test_BEFORE_UPDATE_TEST (
  IN id int(5),
  OUT status enum(‘pass’, ‘fail’)
)
begin
   @status = ‘pass’;

END;
```

What is wrong with this code, as I get unexpected result as null in the value `@updatedStatus`, which should be `'pass'`.

I looked around following QAs on stackoverflow but could't find solution.

- [MySQL procedure subquery returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340791/mysql-procedure-subquery-returns-null)
- [OUT parameter of MySQL stored procedure is null after calling stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828895/out-parameter-of-mysql-stored-procedure-is-null-after-calling-stored-procedure)

I use MySQLWorkbench in MacOS Catalina and version of MySQL is 8.0.19.

Answer (score 2):

The `OUT status` parameter in the procedure is different from the user defined variable `@status`. These are two different variable types altogether.

So, the procedure should look like:

```
create procedure Test_BEFORE_UPDATE_TEST (
IN id int(5),
OUT status enum('pass', 'fail')
)
begin
 set status = 'pass';
END;
```

In the trigger, you should also use normal variables declared with `DECLARE`:

```
create trigger BEFORE_UPDATE_TEST 
before update on test for each row 
begin

declare v_status enum('pass', 'fail');

call Test_BEFORE_UPDATE_TEST(old.id, v_status);

if (v_status is not null and v_status <> new.status) then
  set new.status = v_status;
end if;

end;
```